# Visual Studio 2015 Label Text strange behaviour

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I noticed a very strange behavior on Label Text in C# VS2015 with details from image 1:

[image]

The problem is the following:
If i use round parentheses in Label text when the label is inside a group box then the closing brace is transformed in open brace at the begining of the text(check image: left-how looks like the label on form, right what text i have in label text property)

[image]

If i delete the closing brace, then the first open brace is also deleted(next image)

[image]

If i put the label outside of the group box then the text is shown normaly(check next image)

[image]

Can anyone tell me how can i fix this, and why this occurs ?

Comment: Does it happen on another window / form, have you tried recreating the group box and label? Does it happen in another project?

Comment: In the same project i have already some forms created, also i'm generating some dynamic tab pages with components on it and all labels have the same behaviour on all tab pages even if they are added different. But if i add a new form to the same project, it behaves normal. On other projects of the same solution it also behaves normal. I tried to recreate the label in the same place and it is the  same issue. I don't want to recreate the group box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will happen when the text renderer engine is told to render text right-to-left.  Such as is appropriate in languages like Hebrew and Arabic.  It can still recognize Western glyphs and know that they need to be left-to-right.  But can't do the same for punctuation, like parentheses, they are ambiguous.

Set the groupbox's RightToLeft property back to No.

If it is truly necessary (i.e. the groupbox actually displays RTL text) then set the label's RightToLeft property to No.  Mixing is not a great idea, rethink localization needs.

Comment: You are right, when i changed to No, the problem disappeared.